# Can someone look at my Keras CNN model and help me identify ways to improve the training and validation accuracies?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

```
my_model = models.Sequential() 
#first convolutional block 
my_model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape = (178, 218, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")) 
#add dropout 
my_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
my_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")) 

#second block 
my_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
#add dropout 
my_model.add(Dropout(0.5))

my_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same"))

#third block 
my_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
#add dropout 
my_model.add(Dropout(0.5))

my_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same"))

#fourth block 
my_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
#add dropout 
my_model.add(Dropout(0.5))

my_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")) 

#global average pooling 
my_model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

#fully connected layer 
my_model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
my_model.add(BatchNormalization())

#make predictions 
my_model.add(Dense(18, activation="softmax")) 

from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint 
es = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", mode="min",verbose=1, patience=5) 

mc = ModelCheckpoint('/content/model.h5', monitor="val_loss", mode="min", verbose=1, save_best_only=True) 

cb_list=[es,mc]  

# compile model 
from keras.optimizers import Adam 
my_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.00005),loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]) 

from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

#set up data generator 
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input) 

#get batches of training images from the directory 
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/output7/train',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/output7/val',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical') 

history = my_model.fit(train_generator, epochs = 100, steps_per_epoch=350, validation_data = validation_generator, validation_steps = 100, callbacks = cb_list)
```

This is my code for a model for image classification using keras in Google Colab with Python. Right now I'm stuck with around 30% training accuracy and 10% validation accuracy. Any resources I can look at or suggestions of specific code modifications I can make would be helpful!

Some background information: I chose to add dropout layers to help reduce any instances of overfitting. The images are stored in 18 different classes. There are approximately 11000 training images and 2800 validation images.

Comment: Your dropout layers seem to cause underfitting.

Comment: @Frightera should I remove some or all of them or change the rate? That's the opposite affect I was hoping for :/

Comment: Remove them all first, add them if you are **overfitting**. Also 0.5 rate can be considered as an aggressive rate.

Comment: So I reran it with none, and it got to 83% accuracy for training and 62% for validation. This is overfitting, right? I'm gonna run it again with a dropout layer with a lower rate.

Comment: Looking at loss values might be a better indicator that to conclude you are overfitting. Probably you are overfitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have way to much dropout. Remove all the drop out layers except the last one and set the rate at about .3. In your early stopping checkpoinnt add the parameter
restore_best_weights=True. This will cause your model to end training wiith the weights set to those of the epoch with the lowest validation loss. Then you do not need the checkpoint callback which slows down training. Also add an adjustable learning using the Keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau. Set it to monitor validation loss as in the code below:

```
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", 
                                            factor=0.5,patience=10, verbose=1)
```

add rlronp to the list of callbacks. You are making assumptions about over fiting. You need to monitor the training loss and validation loss as the model trains. Over fitting is when the training loss continues to reduce while the validation loss starts trending upward. If that starts to happen in the early epochs then increase the amount of dropout. If it starts to happen in the later epochs the early stopping callback should trip and return the best weights to the model.

Comment: Your advice was golden. Thank you! I followed your advice and got 99% training accuracy and 82% validation accuracy. My next goal is to get validation accuracy up to 94%...

Comment: glad it helped your model